# How can I compare a JsonPath value with a header in MockMvc?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-test, jsonpath

I am testing a REST API that creates a resource and returns a status of 201 Created and the location of the new resource in both the body and the `Location` header. I would like to assert that these are equal using the MockMvc DSL.

I know how to write a condition for a header:

```
.andExpect(header().string(LOCATION, value))
```

and how to write one for JsonPath:

```
.andExpect(jsonPath("$.data.links.self.href"), equalTo(value))
```

but I don't see a way in the DSL to perform a capture and compare them to each other. I know that [I can supply an arbitrary lambda](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50366343/1189885), but is there a built-in expression for this use case?

Comment: sorry i did not get your question, what are you trying to test

Comment: @Deadpool As I said, I want to test that the URL inside the JSON body and the URL inside the `Location` header are the same.